# What is the use of iter in python?

Tags: python, iteration, keyword

What is the use of using the `iter` function in python?

Instead of doing:

```
for i in range(8):
  print i
```

I could also use `iter`:

```
for iter in range(8):
  print iter
```

Comment: Your code is identical. You just renamed the loop variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all: [`iter()` normally is a function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter). Your code *masks* the function by using a local variable with the same name. You can do this with *any* built-in Python object.

In other words, you are **not** using the `iter()` function here. You are using a for loop variable that happens to use the same name. You could have called it `dict` and it would be no more about dictionaries than it is about Guido's choice of coffee. From the perspective of the `for` loop, there is **no** difference between your two examples.

You'd otherwise use the `iter()` function to produce an [iterator type](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types); an object that has a `.next()` method (`.__next__()` in Python 3).

The `for` loop does this for you, normally. When using an object that can produce an iterator, the `for` statement will use the C equivalent of calling `iter()` on it. You would only use `iter()` if you were doing other iterator-specific stuff with the object.

Answer (score 0):

`iter()` is a Python built-in function that returns an iterator object, which is an object that represent some data. For example, it could be used with a `.next()` method on the iterator that will give you the next element - StopIteration will occur when there are no more elements.