# Do we really need to use built in iter in all for loops of our iterables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using iter in our for loop makes programming an efficient one in python. How does it actually works?

Tried to visualize iter(iterables) in "http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display". Here iter helps to create an instance. 
Doesn't it actually refer to internal numerical objects?

```
val = [1,2,3,4,5]
val = iter(val)
for item in val:
    print(item)

val = [1,2,3,4,5]
for item in val:
    print(item)
```

Both returns same output. But how iter identifies the values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the use of iter in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401944/what-is-the-use-of-iter-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is redundant. A for loop is essentially syntactic sugar for:

```
val = [1,2,3,4,5]
iterator = iter(val)
while True:
    try:
        item = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    print(item)
```

All that you're doing by calling `iter()` on your val is replacing

```
iterator = iter(val)
```

with

```
iterator = iter(iter(val))
```

Calling `iter()` on an iterator is a no-op; returning the same iterator.

Comment: Thanks for jumping in.
But not clear on, what you are trying to convey here.

First I have declared/assigned list to val. - (type(val) will give you list). Next I'm converting to iterator using iter().

My question is - how iterators are more efficient over iterables in looping, as both returns same objects at the end? how iterator internally store the integer data objects?

Comment: My point is: The for loop already calls `iter()` on your list, whether you want it or not. For-loops _always_ loop over iterators, because they convert whatever you want to loop over into an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Lets pretend that Python lists were not iterable and we wanted to create a class, `MyList`, that could be constructed with a `list` instance and iterate it. `MyList` would need to implement a `__iter__` method that would return an iterator object that implements the `__next__` method. Each successive call to this `__next__` method should return the next element of the list. When there are no more elements to be returned, it needs to raise a `StopIteration` exception. This iterator object clearly needs two pieces of information:

1. A reference to the list being iterated.
2. The index of the last element that was output.

Let's call this iterator class `MyListIterator`. Its implementation might be:

```
class MyListIterator:
    def __init__(self, l):
        self.l = l # the list being iterated
        self.index = -1 # the index of the last element outputted

    def __next__(self):
        self.index += 1 # next index to output
        if self.index < len(self.l):
            return self.l[self.index]
        raise StopIteration
```

Class `MyList` then would be:

```
class MyList:
    def __init__(self, the_list):
        self.l = the_list # we are constructed with a list

    def __iter__(self):
        return MyListIterator(self.l) # pass to the iterator our list
```

An example of use:

```
l = MyList([0, 1, 2])
for i in l:
    for j in l:
        print (i, j)
```

Prints:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 1
1 2
2 0
2 1
2 2
```